# ReadFailure in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

I actually want to do this query :

```
SELECT count(oid4) FROM basic_data WHERE o_type_bin_ CONTAINS '383188992';
```

I already create an index on my list, but i have this answer :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/cqlsh.py", line 1277, in perform_simple_statement
    result = future.result()
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 3822, in     cassandra.cluster.ResponseFuture.result (cassandra/cluster.c:74332)
    raise self._final_exception
ReadFailure: Error from server: code=1300 [Replica(s) failed to execute read] message="Operation failed - received 0 responses and 1 failures" info={'failures': 1, 'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'ONE'}
```

When i'm doing query which is not on a list, i have no problem

Comment: Does the Cassandra node log any error?

Comment: The query might have taken longer time to execute, check your timeout configured. Check your query execution time using cqlsh client.